# probleme rendering in django

Tags: python, django

i'm using an api to get informations about coronavirus cases around the world and i have an issue in the last line of code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
from django import forms
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .forms import homeform

def home(request):




    if request.method =='POST':

        form = homeform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            text = form.cleaned_data
            field = text['name']
            print(field)
            country = field

    else:

        form = homeform()
        country = 'algeria'
    url = "https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics"
    querystring = {"country": country}




    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-host': "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com",
        'x-rapidapi-key': "36b864062emshac7e191eb5087e6p169e6bjsn24c86f3408c1"
           }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()
    data = response['response']
    print(data)
    d = data[0]
    context = {
        'all': d['cases']['total'],
        'recovered': d['cases']['recovered'],
        'deaths': d['deaths']['total'],
        'new': d['cases']['new'],
        'serioz': d['cases']['critical'],
        'active':d['cases']['active'],
        'deaths_new':d['deaths']['new']
        }




    return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form}, context)
```

here i have a problem with rendering the page it just shows my html code in the webpage but when i remove context from the last line of code evrything becomes normal , please help me

Comment: What happens if you add: ```'form' :form``` to the context and only pass context

Comment: I wouldn't recommend displaying your api key publicly, as with it others could send requests as you and create avoidable expenses on your account. It will show up in the edit history, so generate a new key

Comment: i got invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to pass two context dictionaries. Your {'form':form} is in the place of the context argument so your context isn't actually getting passed as a context. Add the form to the context dictionary in the line above return and remove {'form':form} from your render function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your code to this :

```
return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form, 
                                     'context':context})
```

This way you will get both in the `html` file.